# Comment « morfondre » provient-il de l'art vétérinaire ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, santé-et-médecine

Je sais que les droits des animaux (et de l'homme) n'existaient pas à l'époque où l'ancien français était parlé, mais certains étaient-ils à ce point sans-cœur qu'ils liquéfiaient ou dissolvaient les animaux vivants pour les tuer ?

Le Wiktionnaire donne cette étymologie [[Ancien français morfondre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morfondre#fro)]:

> On a dit[[1]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morfondre#cite_note-Littr%C3%A9-1) qu’il est composé de *[mort](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mort#fr)* et *[fondre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fondre#fro)* : « fondre jusqu'à la mort ». Mais, comme le mot est originairement de l'art vétérinaire, il faut[[1]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morfondre#cite_note-Littr%C3%A9-1) y voir, avec Ménage un composé, réduit par [haplologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/haplologie), de *[morve](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morve#fro)* et *fondre*. Certains[[2]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morfondre#cite_note-TLFi-2) en font un composé dont la première partie est [*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aide:Formes_reconstruites)*mor* (« tête ») qui est dans *[morail](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morail#fro), [moraille](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moraille#fro)* (« têtière »).

Answer (score 4):

*Morfondre* vient du provençal *marfondre*, « devenir catarrheux, en parlant du cheval ». Composé de *mar/more* « le groin, le museau », et de *fondre*. Le mot a été introduit en médecine vétérinaire où l'on parle d'un *cheval morfondu* (1407), c'est à dire un cheval  qui, [saisi par le froid](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_91QAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22cheval+morfondu%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuxuDgsMrjAhXsD2MBHa4fCs8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), est devenu catarrheux (source : *[Dictionnaire historique de la langue française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_historique_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)*, 1998). Un cheval morfondu a le museau qui coule (il « fond »<sup>1</sup>).

Voir aussi le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/morfondu) :

> a) «devenir catarrheux (du cheval)» (Froissart, Chron., III, §153, éd. L. et A. Mirot, t.13, p.209); b) 1407 cheval morfondu (Arch. Nord B 10361, fol. 44 ds IGLF); 2. a) α) 1460-66 «prendre froid» (Martial d'Auvergne, Arrêts d'amour, éd. J. Rychner, III, 52); β) 1524 adj. subst. morfondu «celui qui est transi de froid (G. Briçonnet, Correspondance, 17 mars, éd. Chr.Martineau et M. Veissière, t.2, p.137);

La formulation du wiktionnaire «  On a dit que...  [...] il faut y voir... »  écarte l'hypothèse d'une étymologie basée sur le mot « mort » et dit bien que le mot est d'origine vétérinaire. Il n'est nulle part question dans l'étymologie de « dissoudre des animaux vivants » ! Répondre à la question « certains auraient-ils eu si peu de cœur que de liquéfier ou dissoudre les animaux vivants pour les tuer ? » ne serait d'ailleurs pas du ressort de *French Language* !

---

<sup>1</sup> « Fondre » vient du latin *fundere* qui vient d'une racine indo-européenne exprimant l'idée d'un liquide versé abondamment et de façon continue. D'abord employé au sens de « s'effondrer, être détruit », relevé jusqu'au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, *fondre* prend au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle ses princiaples valeurs modernes : il signifie en emploi transitif « répandre, verser » (1112) et en emploi intransitif « **couler** » (v. 1160)  (Source : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*.)